# Zig zag border on a button which also has an inner dotted border

Tags: css, border, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I'm trying to do a zig zag border on a button. I have googled one solution, but the zig zag border in this solution is at the bottom, but I needed it at the right side.

I was trying to rewrite the solution, but unfortunately the linear gradient is too hard for me. I was only able to create weird shapes.

Can you, please, help me to rewrite the solution to be on the right?

My CSS:

```
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 30px, white 30px), linear-gradient(-135deg, white 15px, transparent 15px), linear-gradient(135deg, white 15px, transparent 15px);
-webkit-mask-position: left bottom;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-x;
-webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%, 30px 30px, 30px 30px;
```

[LIVE PREVIEW.](https://jsfiddle.net/1vhb3xq6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just have to change the gradient's angles, its size, position and repeat settings like in below snippet. The changes are self explanatory and so I am not detailing them much (*leave me a comment if you need more explanation*).

The other change that I've done is to remove the `outline` and move the dotted border to a pseudo. I have done this because masks work only till the border of the element and not the `outline`, so when the mask is applied, the outline will also get masked out.

(*The below snippet uses masks and so will not work in non-Webkit browsers, the second one would*).

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #99c94d;
  border: none;
  color: #475b28;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  
  /* add the following */
  padding: 8px;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(-225deg, white 5px, transparent 5px), linear-gradient(45deg, white 5px, transparent 5px);
  -webkit-mask-position: left top, right top, right top;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-y;
  -webkit-mask-size: calc(100% - 10px) 100%, 10px 15px, 10px 15px;
}
button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 8px); /* 100% - top padding */
  width: calc(100% - 12px); /* 100% - right padding - buffer */
  top: 4px;  /* half of top padding */
  left: 4px; /* half of left padding */
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #5b7731 transparent #5b7731 #5b7731;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tall {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</button>
<button type="submit" class="wide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Some more text</button>
<button type="submit" class="tall">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</button>
```

---

**Using Background instead of Masks:**

Masks have poor browser support and work only on WebKit powered browsers. To produce a cross-browser output, we could use `background-image` instead of `mask-image`.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: none;
  color: #475b28;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  
  /* add the following */
  padding: 8px; /* to give space before the dotted border */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#99c94d, #99c94d), linear-gradient(-225deg, #99c94d 5px, transparent 5px), linear-gradient(45deg, #99c94d 5px, transparent 5px);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: left top, right top, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: calc(100% - 10px) 100%, 10px 15px, 10px 15px;
}
button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 8px); /* 100% - top padding */
  width: calc(100% - 12px); /* 100% - right padding - buffer */
  top: 4px;  /* half of top padding */
  left: 4px; /* half of left padding */
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #5b7731 transparent #5b7731 #5b7731;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}  
.tall {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</button>
<button type="submit" class="wide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Some more text</button>
<button type="submit" class="tall">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

i would go, at this time,  just with the gradient drawn from a pseudo, so it can be avalaible also for a few other browser. for old browsers , you'll see the dooted border all around.

```css
button {
  color:white;
  margin:15px;
  padding:0px 15px;
  border:dotted  2px;
  background: #99c94d;  
  box-shadow:
    -3px -3px #99c94d,
    -3px 3px #99c94d;
  position:relative;/* to place the pseudo */
}
button:before {/* draw the triangles shapes and hide the right border */
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  /* coordonates : mind the border size and offset shadow */
  right:-9px;
  top:-5px;
  bottom:-5px;
  width:10px;/* whatever you need */
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,#99c94d 29%,transparent 30% ) 0 0  repeat, linear-gradient(-225deg,#99c94d 29%,transparent 30% )0 0 repeat;/* draw the trinagles to produce the repeating shape, you could also  use repeating linear-gradients to skip background-size  */
  background-size:20px 15px; /* size shape */
}
body {
  background:#333;
}
```

```html
<button>button dotted zigzaged </button> <button>another zigzaged <br/>button dotted</button>
```